# Check with what module Guice injector was created

Tags: java, guice

I have an implemented module:

```java
class Product1Module extends AbstractModule {
   ...
}
```

Then I create Guice Injector:

```java
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new Product1Module());
```

Next in my tests I want to override existing module with `Product2Module`. And I can repeat this step few times in different directions. I want to check which module was last before each next overriding.

Is there a method to check it? Something like:

```java
injector.createdByModule(Product1Module.class);
```

As result, I want to have something like:

```java
if (injector.createdByModule(Product1Module.class)) {
    Modules.override(new Product1Module()).with(new Product2Module());
}
else{
    Modules.override(new Product2Module()).with(new Product1Module());
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing. This kind of requests really tend to be [XY problems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire in our tests for each product we extend basic module, which have main logic, where at the start of tests is created Guice injector for product in which module we are. But we want to extend functionality and create tests for two products, and now we have two products in one module. In this case basic module create injector with random picked product (specific of basic module) and in our test we want override existing injector by specific product. And also I don't want override module if that module already was injected.

Answer (score 0):

`Bindings` inside `Injector` instance contain info about their `Module`. You can get this info like that:

```
injector.getBindings().forEach((k, b) -> System.out.println(k.toString() + " " + b.getSource()));
```

BTW I agree with Olivier's comment, your approach seems to be overcomplicated. Probably you just can have a separate injector for every product.

Comment: When I run the code above I get smth like: `Key[type=my.project.Client, annotation=[none]] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)` and here no info about if this is from Product1Module or Product2Module. How I said before we extend basic module, which we cant change, where we create injector for module and later we can only override that injector